# Apply rollmean, but keeping the single value if a company does not have k > 2

Tags: r, zoo

I have a dataset that I wand to apply rollmean to smooth data values. However, for some of my observations I only have the first value, so I would to keep it in place of the default `NA`. To achieve this, I'm filtering data for those I've more than k>2, so I can simply apply the following code. For those k < 2, I just plug them latter. Is there I better way of doing this?

- Some toy data

```
df <- tibble(city = sample(LETTERS[1:11], 10, rep=TRUE), 
    deaths = sample(1000:10000, 10, rep=TRUE))
```

```
df %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(city)) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(city) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(roll = zoo::rollmean(deaths, k = 2, fill = NA, align="right")) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   city  deaths  roll
   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
 1 K       9292   NA 
 2 K       7339 8316.
 3 J       3537   NA 
 4 J       1207 2372 
 5 G       4994   NA 
 6 F       2185   NA 
 7 F       1408 1796.
 8 E       4254   NA 
 9 D       5269   NA 
10 B       5448   NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected output you could chose one of the option below. Also `rollmean(... , align = 'right')` is equal to `rollmeanr`.

1. You can check for number of rows in a group and keep the `death` value for rows = 1. Note that, this will still give `NA`'s for first value where number of rows is greater than 1.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(city)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(city) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(roll = if(n() == 1) deaths else zoo::rollmeanr(deaths, k = 2, fill = NA))
```

2. You can use `fill = first(deaths)` to get first value as default for all first value. This will replace `NA` in each group to first value of that group. So change the last line to :

```
dplyr::mutate(roll = zoo::rollmeanr(deaths, k = 2, fill = first(deaths)))
```

3. You can use `rollaplyr` with `partial = TRUE`. When `k = 2` it will give same output as `(2)` but if you change the window-size you'll see the difference.

```
dplyr::mutate(roll = zoo::rollapplyr(deaths, width = 2, FUN = mean, partial = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use the `partial = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(city)) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(city) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(roll = zoo::rollmean(deaths, k = 2, fill = NA, 
                 align="right", partial = TRUE)) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   city  deaths  roll
#   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
# 1 K       2128   NA 
# 2 K       1877 2002.
# 3 G       2300   NA 
# 4 G       9228 5764 
# 5 E       6921 6921 -> single value
# 6 C       9676 9676 -> single value
# 7 B       2798   NA 
# 8 B       9920 6359 
# 9 A       9521   NA 
#10 A       8844 9182.
```

Comment: I'm giving @ronak-shah the credit because his answer is more complete and item 2 is the desired result I was in mind when I post this question.